# launcher icon and push icon size issue

Tags: android, push

Why my launcher icon is small in size. Is it the image issue only or am doing some wrong setting.I used image asset to set launcher icon.

Also the manifest application part is like

```
<application
 android:name=".Abc"
 android:allowBackup="true"
 android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
 android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:theme="@style/AppTheme">......
```

Also the push icon is coming too small while i send the notification.

[image]

Push code
      public void onCreate() {
              super.onCreate();
              Parse.initialize(this, "..", "..");
              ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
             ...}

Comment: add please notification Java code

Comment: i am using parse push notification

Comment: it seems to be that you do not have all sizes for your icon

Comment: I saw, image asset automatically makes size in different folders like hdpi, mdpi etc.So now which icon size you referring?

Comment: it seemas that it takes only from one folder. to make sure you need to test it on more than one device

Answer (score 0):

Did you set all the icons for all screen sizes? 
I usually use [this template](http://appicontemplate.com/android/) for generating my icon, than I use the [Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html) for generating it at different scales.

Answer (score 0):

Use notification manager to create notification. Try this

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.launcher);

NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL);

        final Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setLargeIcon(bm)
                .setContentTitle("Application")
                .setContentText("New Message")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setTicker("New Message from a User")
                .setVibrate(new long[]{200, 1000, 200, 1000})
                .setLights(Color.WHITE, 3000, 3000)
                .getNotification();

        mNotificationManager.notify(10000, notification);
```